# Get a color 3D point cloud from depth image and RGB(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am done with the code 3D point cloud by using depth.
using Media3D class.

I hope to develop a program to get a kinect depth image and RGB image and convert it into color 3D point cloud as my final year project.

I just wanted to know how can I apply ts corresponding RGB points. Plus how can I put my RGB points to its corresponding triangle?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Sumit bhau tumhi kelela konatahi code paste kara, nahitar hi lokk downvote karatil tumhala.

Comment: bhau mala to depth cha code mahiey..ani kharach mahit nahi rao kasa wicharaycha..

Comment: aaho aaj tumhi marathi aahat mhanun mi tumacha question downvote kinwa flag kela nahi , pan ithe prashn vicharanya aadhi i have tried this: aasa mhanun konatahi aapan kelela[failure aasala tari chalel] code paste karayacha. nahitar lokk aapala question downvote kinwa flag karatat.

Comment: Can we please keep the comments in English? This is after all an English language site. And your question simply is, how to map the color stream's pixels to the depth stream's (converted) 3d points?

Comment: is it ok..?or shall I post d cose...freelancer bhau plz madat kara..tumhala sangu shakat nahi etkya wait tension madhe ahe mi..!

Comment: I believe the [CoordinateMapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663710.aspx) will allow you to get the information you are looking for.